# Password generation in C# using Membership.GeneratePassword and without white spaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, password-encryption

Could anyone confirm me if this method generates a password without white spaces (blanks)?

I think it generates without white spaces, but I would like someone confirm me this.

In the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(v=vs.110).aspx) it is not talked about white spaces.

Comment: Well, [here's the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/Membership.cs#L302-L365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp) to me:

> The generated password **only contains alphanumeric characters and the following punctuation marks**: !@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?. No hidden or non-printable control characters are included in the generated password.

No mention of including whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

> The generated password only contains alphanumeric characters and the following punctuation marks: !@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?. No hidden or non-printable control characters are included in the generated password.

So it shouldn't contain whitespace characters

Answer (score 1):

According to [the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/Membership.cs#L302-L365), it generates passwords using the characters:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- any of **!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?**